# $(window).load(function()) and NProgress JQuery Plugin. Page is fully loaded, but NProgress is still working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I tried to use [NProgress Plugin](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress), but got into problem.

When my page is fully loaded, NProgress is still working. Try it your-self.

Here is my code.

Index.html:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nprogress.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
NProgress.start();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
NProgress.done();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it the other way round.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   NProgress.done();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   NProgress.start();
});
```

`$(document).ready()` fires as soon as DOM is ready (The HTML structure) and the `$(window).load()` fires when all the images, scripts etc.. are loaded.

Your method didn't work because you were starting the NProgress when everything was loaded and document is already ready so `.done()` wasn't called.